# -D argument doesn't work for Java

Tags: java, netbeans

When passing a system property to the Java VM with the -D command, I am getting a null result when using `System.getProperty`

I am using Netbeans. After setting the property shown in the picture below, I am getting `null` when calling `System.getProperty("debugMode")`

[image]

Comment: Can you show your command line exactly ?

Comment: It seems to be working in other ide. It could be issue in netbeans. Have you tried running application on command line instead of just through netbeans?

Comment: Can you try running this through the command line instead of as a vm option through netbeans.

Comment: GlassFish probably isn't modifying its deployment script to accept new options from your IDE.

Comment: Are you *running* this through NetBeans? Because if you aren't, that setting doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the quotes ("") from argument so it looks like this:

```
-DdebugMode=true
```